# Ext JS store data not loading

Tags: extjs, combobox, store

For some reason unknown to me, I cannot get my Ext JS store to display in my combobox

Here's my model:

Type.js

```
Ext.define('AM.model.Type', { //app name config is "AM"
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'field', type: "string" }
    ]
});
```

And my store:

Type.js

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Type', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.Type',
    storeId: 'typestore',
    data: [
        { field: 'Bobby' },
        { field: 'Jimbo' },
        { field: 'Craig' }

     ]
 });
```

And where I call it:

app.js

```
{ xtype: 'combobox', padding: 5, store: Ext.getStore('typestore'), displayField: 'field'}...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Come up with anything? Can't find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by instantiating my store class with into a variable using `Ext.Create`
and setting my comboboxes `queryMode` to `local` (remote would display the data but keep on loading and loading).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong here. The problem is probably elsewhere. 
I have created a sample `fiddle` with your code slightly simplified, and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/28sX7/